# Checking if param is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm relatively new to Rails and busy building an app with various access levels, for instance global_admin and company_admin. Now company_admin should only have access to a specific company and no others.

My routes:

```
  resources :companies do
    resources :groups do
      resources :users
    end
  end
```

I created a helper to check access which contains the following:

```
 if params[:company_id].present?
   @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
   ...
```

So if I call, for instance ^/companies/1/groups ^/companies/1/groups/1/users the query returns true and finds the company_id, but if I call ^/companies/1 or ^/companies/2 it returns false. Why is it not picking up the company_id if it is (or at least seems to be) present?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're not accessing a nested resource, `params[:company_id]` becomes `params[:id]` instead.

Same thing with groups. If you access `/companies/1/groups/1`, `params[:id]` would give you the group's id, but if you access `/companies/1/groups/1/users/1`, `params[:id]` would give you the user's id instead, and the group's id would be in `params[:group_id]`.